# Object expect in in java-script

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting the constant error that it is expecting an object.

I call a function onchange:

```
        <select name =<?php echo $dagen[$i]."1"; ?> id=<?php echo $dagen[$i]."1"; ?> onchange="weekchange(this, <?php echo $i; ?>)" />
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
function weekchange(selected, weekkeuze)
{
var samen;
var id = weekkeuze;
var week  = selected.value;
samen = "id="+id+"&week="+week;
alert(samen);
submit_javascript("GET","capaciteitberekening.php?"+samen,"","true"); //row 13
}
```

In this function I receive the data from the onchange correctly since it shows the correct values in the alert(samen), with the last sentence I should be sending this data to capaciteitberekening.php. here I am not sure what is going on. On capaciteitberekening.php I use this code to catch the value:

```
$filt['week'] = $_GET['week'];
$filt['id'] = $_GET['id'];
echo $id, $week;
```

But as you might expect I do not receive anything, instead i get an error on my browser saying that it is expecting a object in row 13.

I hope you can help me, since I have no clue how to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the rendered html

Comment: Could you add the definition of the `submit_javascript` function?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reminding me about the function, I am working om someone else his code so I didn't look properly at that function. and I had to add a ID and not a class, sorry for making such a basic mistake, and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for reminding me about the function, I am working om someone else his code so I didn't look properly at that function. and I had to add a ID and not a class, sorry for making such a basic mistake, and thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could be some issue with your php code at line 13.

To check if the values are posted correctly,
try this at the beginning of capaciteitberekening.php.

```
<?php 
var_dump($_GET);
exit;
?>
```

If It works, then its sure that there could be some other issue with your php code in capaciteitberekening.php, but request is working fine.